# Postions of Divs in Desktop and mobile view

Tags: html, css, polymer

```
        <div class$="{{_classForListWrapper(filtered)}} conversation-section">
          <div id="convo-list-wrapper" class="conversation-list">
              <gm-conversation-list language-code="{{languageCode}}"                   
                                    first-result="{{firstResult}}"
                                    results="{{results}}">
              </gm-conversation-list>
          </div>
        </div>

        <template is="dom-if" if="{{!filtered}}">
            <div id="convo-tags-wrapper"class="col-md-9 col-lg-8 conversation-chatbox">
              <template is="dom-if" if="{{openConversation}}">
                <gm-conversation
                  id="conversation1"
                  conversation="{{conversation}}"
                  show-tool-tip="{{showToolTip}}"
                  tool-tip-step="{{toolTipStep}}"
                  base-url="{{baseUrl}}"
                ></gm-conversation>
              </template>
          </div>
        </template>
```

I have left div and right div in desktop view. Left div has chat list. Right div has one selected chat details. (The chat Selected from left chat list div) In mobile view, it should display Left chat list div. After selecting the specific chat from the chat list div(Left div) it should display the selected chat details in separate mobile UI. Please help me to explain with simple code.

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: what you had done so far.

Comment: please create a code snippet of your working code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of information, this is the simplest piece of code I can come up with(Change the width to see the mediaquery effect):

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',function(e) {
 let rightSide = document.getElementById('right');
 let leftSide = document.getElementById('left');
 rightSide.style.display = 'block';
 leftSide.style.display = 'none';
 e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 color: #fff;
}

.left {
 flex: 3;
 background: red;
}

.right {
 flex: 1;
 background: blue;
}

/* Viewport */
@media (max-width: 576px) {
 .right {
  display: none;
  flex-basis: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="left" id="left">
  <a href="#" id="btn">Click here</a>
 </div>
 <div class="right" id="right">Right</div>
</div>
```